# Reducing jar file size?

Tags: java, jar, compression

Is there a good app to reduce jar file size by eliminating redundant 
classes/methods/constant pool elements? (i.e. not reachable from a fixed
set of entry points, assuming no reflection)

I'm tired of pulling in bloated libraries when I'm just using a couple of methods from them.

(I'm not talking about small "local" optimizations like making names smaller. I'm thinking more of something that does global analysis to figure out which classes/methods/variables are used, given a set of entry points (including reflective entry points), and removes everything that is not used.

My webapp is like, 45MB, mostly due to 30-odd libraries, and I'm pretty sure I'm using only a small fraction of each library.

Comment: @hairraisin I think this will not make a difference (but I could be wrong) since `jars` are [already](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) zip archives (w/ some additional info).

Comment: @hairraisin oh, didn't get that ;)

Answer (score 14):

Yes, there is one - [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/).

> ProGuard is a free Java class file shrinker, optimizer, obfuscator,
>   and preverifier. It detects and removes unused classes, fields,
>   methods, and attributes. It optimizes bytecode and removes unused
>   instructions. It renames the remaining classes, fields, and methods
>   using short meaningless names. Finally, it preverifies the processed
>   code for Java 6 or for Java Micro Edition.

Comment: Thanks! and oh, is there something like this that will directly work on a war file?

Comment: @user1001630 you mean without unzipping? cause otherwise solution [is to use proguard anyways](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2477447/298389)

Comment: I never achieved to do anything using proguard. It allways fails on any jar I tried.

Answer (score 6):

Obfuscation typically reduces jar file size by a respectable factor.

You may want to try tools like [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) (open source) and similar.

You can see some examples of size reduction in this page:

- http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/results.html

Answer (score -1):

Just another nice trick, usually using the unnamed package, which is deleting the name (< default> will appear), also decreases the jar size.

In my case my jar went from 24,243 bytes to 23,946. Yeah not a big deal but still a cool trick i think.

From efficient MIDP programming:

**"Use the 'unnamed package' – placing your MIDlet classes all in the same named package only increases the size of your MIDlet’s JAR file; reserve the package statement for libraries"**
http://carfield.com.hk/document/java/articles/Efficient_MIDP_Programming.pdf