# how to reduce size of jfree library size

Tags: java, jfreechart, embedded-linux

Can anyone tell me how the size of jcommon-1.0.16.jar and jfreechart-1.0.13.jar(mainly jfreechart-1.0.13.jar ) executables can be decreased.i need to reduce size for my embedded product which works on linux environment.

Memory is the biggest problem  in embedded...can anyone help me out.

Comment: Can you get the source and build just the classes you need? If you use code coverage this can help determine that. Note: the memory used by the library is mostly images you create, the size of the code is relatively small.

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=115565).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810896/reducing-jar-file-size) that may point you in the right direction.  [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) was the most popular solution  but I'm afraid I'm no direct experience.

Comment: I have java 1.5 used by my board but ProGaurd seems to be used for java6 and doubt reliability and integrity of the code after its usage.

Comment: Jaba 5 is addressed in the [FAQ](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#FAQ.html).  To check the reliability you could use the Unit Tests included in the JFreeChart distribution.  I'm not sure how you would verify the integrity.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the [Maven Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) , with its minimizejar option

```
        <configuration>
          <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
        </configuration>
```

Remember that only those classes will be included in the jar that have direct dependencies in the code, although Java code can load classes in many other tricky ways.

Answer (score 0):

I used JCC kit for my target platform and it's less than 100kb library. You need to understand  the library and after that you can play without worrying about size. :)