# Reduce the jar file size

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jar, bundle

I have a jar file (created with maven) clocks at more than 800Mb. This is due to duplication amongst the bundles.

The idea is to remove or at the very least reduce the amount of duplication amongst the bundles by making delta zip bundles instead of union zip bundles.

Can any one help me to reduce the jar file size?

Thanks

Comment: **Proguard** check this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/a/7810922/2681245]

Comment: I don't want a software solution. I want a maven solution
thanks

Comment: Could you give an exemple of what you call "bundle duplication" ?

Comment: Can you show your pom?

Comment: My pom file has more then 3000 lines with 14 modules very one has his dependencies that's why I get duplicated jars

Comment: Manage dependencies in your parent pom. BTW we don't need to see your whole pom, just the relevant parts to get an idea what is wrong.